# How to Parcelize data class in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have data class and one variable is type of `Color`. I have logic to store different types of colors to show in UI i.e.

```
data class SubTitleModel(
    val text: String,
    val textColor: Color = Color.Black
)
```

When I am passing from one activity to another activity I have to use `@Parcelize` i.e.

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class SubTitleModel(
    val text: String,
    val textColor: Color = Color.Black
) : Parcelable
```

It giving me error on `Color`

```
Type is not directly supported by 'Parcelize'. Annotate the parameter type with '@RawValue' if you want it to be serialized using 'writeValue()'
```

so what does it mean? How to solve this problem? Please provide detail explanation with proper reference. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to parcelize Compose Color. You can pass as color `Int` type in your `SubtitleModel` and add color with `fun Color(/*@ColorInt*/ color: Int): Color ` in ui

Comment: Can you please provide the example? I didn't get the `fun Color(/*@ColorInt*/ color: Int): Color`?

Comment: The best practice will be store the color in resource/color.kt and use the resource value as Id in data class.

Comment: @J.K can you please give me example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to pass Int or Long instead of passing Compose Color such as

```
data class SubTitleModel(
    val text: String,
    val textColor: Int = (0xFF000000).toInt()
)
```

Then in your ui

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    val modelList = listOf(
        SubTitleModel(
            text = "SomeText"
        ),
        SubTitleModel(
            text = "SomeText2",
            textColor = Color.Red.toArgb()
        ),
        SubTitleModel(
            text = "SomeText3",
            textColor = Color.Green.toArgb()
        )
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {
        modelList.forEach { model: SubTitleModel ->
            Text(text = model.text, color = Color(model.textColor))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As we know the color is a resource that we can kept both in `colors.xml` and `Color.kt`so we may have a color wrapper for this case to store the incoming colors so it wont break if the requirement has changed (some view may be in xml).

This is basically wrapper which can accept both type of colors, we dont wanna worry about where it comes. it could be from xml or kotlin file.

```kotlin
@Parcelize
sealed class ColorWrapper : Parcelable {
    data class ColorResource(
        val resource: Int,
        val text: String,
    ) : ColorWrapper()

    data class ColorHex(
        val hex: ULong,
        val text: String,
    ) : ColorWrapper()
}

fun ULong.toColor() = Color(this)
```

Then we can use those colors in compose like this.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val colors = listOf(
        ColorWrapper.ColorResource(R.color.black, "Black"),
        ColorWrapper.ColorHex(Color.Black.value, "Black"),
    )
    colors.forEach { model: ColorWrapper ->
        when (model) {
            is ColorWrapper.ColorHex -> {
                TextView(text = model.text, color = model.hex.toColor())
            }

            is ColorWrapper.ColorResource -> {
                TextView(text = model.text, color = colorResource(model.resource))
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TextView(text: String, color: Color) {
    Text(text = text, fontSize = 30.sp, color = color)
}
```

This is not overkill solution, its a vision or best practice for me.
btw Thracian's answer is more apt for your situation. Im posting this as you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@RawValue` annotation for that value.
Try to modify `textColor` like this:

```
val textColor: @RawValue Color = Color.Black
```

Comment: what is `@RawValue` ?